# How to combine two queries? MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

How can i combine my two queries?
1:

```
SELECT `dialog_id`
  FROM `messages`
  GROUP BY `dialog_id`
  HAVING COUNT(*) >= 10 
    AND MIN(`timestamp`) + INTERVAL 1 HOUR < MAX(`timestamp`)
```

This query is finding dialogs where more than 10 messages and lasted more than an hour.

2:

```
SELECT * FROM messages tbl WHERE 
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM messages tbl1 WHERE tbl1.dialog_id = tbl.dialog_id AND tbl1.id >= tbl.id AND 
(user_from = :user_from OR user_to = :user_to)) <= 2 ORDER BY dialog_id DESC
```

The second query selects two last rows for each dialogs.

So, what i want is select last two rows for each dialogs that lasted more than an hour and where more than 10 messages.
I want to show them on the dialog preview page.

Sorry for my english it isn't my native language.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use window functions for all these calculations:

```
SELECT m.*
FROM (SELECT m.*,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY dialog_id ORDER BY id DESC) as seqnum,
             COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY dialog_id) as cnt,
             MIN(timestamp) OVER (PARTITION BY dialog_id) as min_timestamp,
             MAX(timestamp) OVER (PARTITION BY dialog_id) as max_timestamp
      FROM messages m
     ) m
WHERE seqnum <= 2 AND
      cnt >= 10 AND
      max_timestamp > min_timestamp + INTERVAL 1 HOUR;
```